# Java api for Sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api, java

I would like to know if there is a java api for the sharepoint server.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

I hope these API will help you

http://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/

http://code.google.com/p/sharepoint-wsdl/

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/connectors/sharepoint/current.html

We can use SharePoint Web Services for connecting from java. 
http://www.infoq.com/articles/swanson-moss-web-services

http://techiehojae.blogspot.in/2009/10/invoking-sharepoint-web-services.html

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't. The SharePoint API is .NET only. However, you could use a Java .NET Bridge like [this](http://www.jnbridge.com/) or you could use the SharePoint Webservices.

The SharePoint Webservices are "normal" SOAP webservices, so you consume them just like any other... i don't know java, but i assume there is a tool that let you create a (client) class based on a WSDL file. [Here](http://panvega.wordpress.com/2007/09/15/consuming-listsapsx-webservice-from-sharepoint/) is a good tutorial showing you the basics.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply... but how to use the sharepoint webservices?? any useful link?? Will I be able to do everything in java, or i will also need some .NET programming ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: i edited my answer.. yes you can use most of the functionallity with the webservices but it really depends on your requirements... in my experience, most of the time i create my own custom web service that sits on top of SharePoint so i can abstract some of the business logic into that service, which simplifies the handling within my client. in this case, you would use .NET to create that web service

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of alternatives  int32 is only favorizing his own product I think, there are free libraries that can do this https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/

Answer (score -1):

JShare from Independentsoft. It looks very promising for Java and Android.

Comment: Thanks for joining the answerers at StackOverflow, just one point, the generaly culture here is that posts aren't signed (ie don't have signatures) ...

Comment: JShare has terrible suport!